# Python Youtube-dl convert to mp4

Tags: python, ffmpeg, mp4, data-conversion, youtube-dl

(if it matters, I'm on windows)

So I am trying to download a Youtube video in an Mp4 format (the program I am putting it into has limited compatibility) with audio but whatever I find online either doesn't work how people are saying it does (leading me to believe it is either outdated, missing context, or for a different OS) or is formatted in a way that doesn't make sense.

My current code is :

```
if PreferredOutput == 1:
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({'format' : 'bestvideo+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/bestvideo+bestaudio/best', 'merge-output-format' : 'mp4'}) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])
```

but when I test it, it just seems to output the file as normal.(which I am guessing is the format the video file was uploaded to youtube as though I could be mistaken) What should I do/am I missing to make this only output (final) Mp4s? (after the fact ffmpeg conversion or something similar is fine for my purposes)

Comment: many of the answers I have found are formatted like this ``` youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/mp4' url ```however this does not seem to work in python when I test it. I don't fully understand where this DOES even apply, but it doesn't seem to apply to python scripting.

Comment: The command which does the work is ``` youtube-dl -f bestvideo+bestaudio url --recode-video mp4 ``` but I'm not able to get this to work from code. Did you find anything which works from code?

Answer (score 4):

Add the below option to convert videos to mp4.

```
'postprocessors': [{
    'key': 'FFmpegVideoConvertor',
    'preferedformat': 'mp4'
}]
```

After downloading the video, it will get converted to mp4 and the original file will get deleted.

Note: The conversion of the video will take a lot of time.